# HTML Left and Right Align Elements

Tags: html, css

To accomplish this I have done this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
 <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;text-align: left;">left</td>
    <td style="width:50%;text-align: right;">right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How could I accomplish this in the simplest fashion (least markup) without using tables? I just want to align 2 elements to the max left and right.

There are hundreds of 2 column layouts out there, but they more aligned for page layout, and seem overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some html:

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
.left, .right {
  width: 50%; /* Floated elements technically need a width specified. */
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Adding text-align: right; to the .right class did just what I needed, thanx.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
#primary {
   width: 100%;
}

.secondary {
   width: 50%;
}

.leftcolumn {
   float: left;
   text-align: left;
} 

.rightcolumn {
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="primary">
   <div class="secondary leftcolumn">
      <p>This will be on the left</p>
   </div>
   <div class="secondary rightcolumn">
      <p>This will be on the right</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Although I'd change `leftcolumn` and `rightcolumn` to something specific to the content that each will contain (in favor of a [semantic](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/11/css-coding-semantic-approach-in-naming.html) naming approach to CSS rather than structural).